# Elastic Beanstalk deploy - ASP.NET from commandline

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, webdeploy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my MVC4 app to ELB.  The project has several post-build steps which pull together dependencies.  The AWS SDK publish wizard then does not do the trick - it builds a Web Deploy package behind the scenes, which does not action those post-build steps or preserve the resulting directory structure.

So, I downloaded the command-line EB tools, got a git repository working, but can't work out the next step: what do I push to the server with `git aws.push`: because if it's just the resulting files then I can't specify the "Enable 32-bit applications" flag (required), etc.  Do I then push a web deploy package from my repository?

I presume so, but if so, how do I include the files copied into the output folder during "normal" builds by my post-build steps?

Comment: Stand by, I have found the "All files in this project folder" option in web deployment configuration in project settings.  I will try that now..

Comment: Having another issue, but my comment may be the answer.  If it would deploy at all.. will update this question if I find out

Comment: Nope, would really appreciate how to do an incremental git push from the commandline for .NET please.

Comment: What the git aws.push is pushing is the contents of the msdeploy archive. In order to use aws.push, you would need to extract the msdeploy archive and make that your local git repo, which is what Visual Studio does when you check the incremental deploy box in the wizard.

Comment: Massively good key info thanks Jim

Comment: Hello Kieren, any Progress on this ? I was looking into this exact problem.

Comment: @fabrizioM Other than the comment reply here, the support case is still open (but escalated). I will update when I get one :)

Comment: @Jim Flanagan - AWS support seems to say it's the zip file not the contents of it - can you comment?

Comment: Actually, You can have the best of both worlds. The AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio includes a command line deployment tool, which will both allow you to set the configurables as well as do the incremental deployment. I should have realized before that this might serve you better. Have a look at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSToolkitVS/latest/UserGuide/tkv-deployment-tool.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go.  This seems to be in conflict with what Jim Flanagan was saying - below it's a zip file, but Jim says it's the contents of it.

@Jim Flanagan - perhaps you could comment if you have some time. Thanks.

Hi thanks for contacting AWS Premium Support

Communication from the Elastic Beanstalk Engineering Team.

When you aws.push an ASP.NET/MVC app you do not push the web deploy archive, rather you push the artifacts as you want them deployed on the machine. From the customers stack overflow question it seems they have already found the local git repo that the VS deployment wizard created and looking their should give them a good indication of what is needed in the git repository.

There isn't a nice way through the aws.push to specify what the "Enable 32-bit Application" app pool setting should be (or any other configuration setting). If you need a specific configuration setting set I would suggest creating the environment (via the console or using the eb command line tool) which allow you to specify the configuration. And then use git aws.push to deploy to that environment, git aws.push will just use the configuration that is already present on the environment.

The last question about still being incremental is not really valid since you are not pushing just one big zip file. But if you were, it could still be incremental depending on what changed in the zip file, it might just send a diff between the two versions of the zip file. As the question implies though that use case is not really what incremental deployments were designed to help with.